# Remove line from chart and draw new one

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to plot the minimal mean squared error function and update that line to every new point that's been added by clicking on that graph. Everything works so far but I can't seem to remove the old line to draw *only* the new one.

This is the code that updates the line - not the points which are updated elsewhere.

```
Graph.prototype.update = function() {

    var this_ = this;
    var data = d3.csv.parse(this.collectData());
    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    this.svg.selectAll("lines").remove();

    lines = this.svg.selectAll("lines")
        .data(data)
        .attr("class", "update");

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "x"; }));

    var lineData = color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {
          name: name,
          values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {x: d.x, y: +d[name]};
          })
        };
    });

    lines.enter().append("path")    
        .data(lineData)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return this_.line(d.values); })
        .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
};
```

And that's how it looks so far:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding the new line, remove any existing lines:

```
// remove existing lines
this.svg.selectAll('lines').remove();

var lines = this.svg.selectAll('lines')
    .data(data);

// the rest of the code here.
```

then, add the line with the new data.

Comment: I've changed the code example to your suggest. But it still shows the same behaviour.

Comment: Alright I needed to call remoe on `this.svg.selectAll("path").remove();`. Now it works! I tried it using [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) example which says that `obj.exit().remove()` should remove the old date. Seems I missunderstood there something.